# Android disable activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I make an activity temporarily not touchable and not focusable  ?

Comment: You want the Activity to remain active, but nothing on its UI to be touchable or focusable?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I want...

Comment: I need a method such as setEnabled(false) but on an activity

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off all the listeners when you want. 
Another approach I have used is to use a transparent Linear Layout or Relative Layout to be inflated to cover the full screen for a period of time.

```
public void coveredScreen(){
    if(point_total>0){
        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view); //whatever your layout is
        loadedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.covered_screen, null); //the layout that contains something that fills parent.

        parent.addView(loadedView);

        updateHandler = new Handler();

        updateHandler.postDelayed(coveredScreen, 2000); //opens layout for 2000 ms

        // turns off listeners...
        button1.setClickable(false);
        button2.setClickable(false);

}

Runnable loadingScreen = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // this turns on listeners and removes the inflated view
          parent.removeView(loadedView); 
          button1.setClickable(true);
          button2.setClickable(true);

        // Call this method again every 3 seconds if desired or as long as wanted by uncommenting this handler
        //updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
      }
    };
```

So... to set this going for as long as you'd like then call everytime you want to block any actions from the user within the Activity.